# 500 Internal Server Error when using .htaccess to always redirect to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am currently building my own PHP-Framework to gain some experience and am following [this](https://medium.com/@noufel.gouirhate/create-your-own-mvc-framework-in-php-af7bd1f0ca19) guide.

However I have some trouble by implementing the .htaccess-files. When I open my website it displays an 500 Internal Server Error.

My folder structure looks as follows:

```
ProjectName/
  |- src/
  |  |- Controller/
  |  |- Model/
  |  |- View/
  |  | .htaccess
  |  | Dispatcher.php
  |  | Request.php
  |  | Router.php
  |  | index.php
  | .htaccess
  | Dockerfile
  | docker-compose.yml
```

The both .htaccess files look like this:

ProjectName/src/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/]*)$ index.php?p=$1
```

ProjectName/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/]*)$ src/$1
```

What's confusing me the most is: If I don't have my .htaccess files implemented and I open my website, then it opens index.php.

Comment: Thanks for sharing detailed question on first. For rule `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/]*)$ src/$1` I believe this is the culprit here, could you please do let me know for which example/sample url you are trying to write this? That way we will get better understanding of question, thank you.

Comment: When you get a 500 error, you need to look at your web server's error log for more details.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I had the same thought and when I had a look in my docker container the logs were empty. Respectively `cat error.log` didn't return any results.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Maybe this will help: I intend to have a Framework where I can call an URL: such as www.example.com/home/page which then is being processed as home being my Controller (PHP Class) and page being the function that's called inside the class "home". Basically the same principle that was described in the article.

Comment: The error log file the http server writes is never empty. At least server starts are noted there. So either you are looking at the wrong file or you explicitly turned off logging. I suggest you start looking into your http server's configuration to find out what is logged where.

Comment: What is the URL you are requesting? What is the `DocumentRoot`? Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled for the entire directory tree? "If I don't have my .htaccess files implemented and I open my website, then it opens index.php" - what URL are you requesting in this case?

Comment: @MrWhite I seem to have found my problem. My docker image is `php:7.2-apache` and as it seems `mod_rewrite` isn't enabled. After I ran `a2enmod rewrite` it worked just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My docker-image is of `php:7.2-apache` and as it seems `mod-rewrite` wasn't enabled. Therefore after running the command `a2enmod rewrite` my website worked again.